# Getting product version from file via cmd/bat

Tags: cmd, getfileversion

I have a file with Version resource that File vesrion/Product version fields are filled. I need to retrieve Product version via BAT file. Example, I have File with ProductVersion 1.0.1 in the output of bat file I wan't to have string "101" or "1.0.1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to use the Filever.exe tool to obtain specific information about a file in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913111/en-us)

From what I gather about `filever`'s output it's always in columns and you want the fifth column (version). So a simple `for` should suffice:

```
for /f "tokens=5 delims= " %%v in ('filever myFile.dll /b') do echo %%v
```

Comment: I know about Filever, but it gaves too many information. Could you help me in parsing output of filever?

Comment: @zabalus: See edit. I didn't find `filever` for Windows 7 so I couldn't test directly but the code works for the sample output given in the KB article.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`sigcheck`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897441.aspx) tool which is part of [Sysinternals Suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) since [`filever`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/913111) is quiet old, e.g.

```
$ sigcheck.exe -q -n app.exe
5.0.0.1241
```

By specifying `-q` (quiet) and `-n`, it'll show you only the file version number.

Comment: Great, that's what I was looking for. Pitty you've answered 5 years after that :). Still good answer

Comment: Support for Filever.exe tool ended. +1 to this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For dummy's like me there is one correction in the above statement to get the value of product version it would be like:

```
for /f "tokens=5 delims= " %%v in ('filever myFile.dll /b /v') do echo %%v
```

the `/v` parameter was missing and I am unable to get the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

To read version from resource RC-file you can use:

```
for /F "tokens=3" %%a in ( 'findstr ProductVersion YourProgram.rc' ) do set VERSION=%%~a
```